# Cystoscape node color

Tags: r, cytoscape

I'm using `RCy3` R package, I've already built a network using some gene expression data, how can I color some nodes in another way, different than the default one? I searched through the package documentation but is a bit cryptic, is there anyone that already did something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3 - this is how .....

```
from py2cytoscape.data.cyrest_client import CyRestClient
from py2cytoscape import cyrest

cy = CyRestClient()
#Remove previous Networks !!
cy.session.delete()
cytoscape=cyrest.cyclient()

network = cy.network.create(name='Test', collection='UK Prem League')
# Add 4 Nodes
network.add_node("Prem League")
network.add_node("Newcastle")
network.add_node("Liverpool")
network.add_node("Man City")
df_network=network.get_node_table()

def get_node_id(node_str):
    return list(df_network[df_network.name==node_str]['SUID'])[0]
# Add an Edge
network.add_edge(get_node_id("Newcastle"),get_node_id("Liverpool"),True)
#Select Newcastle
cytoscape.network.select(nodeList='Newcastle',verbose=False)
#Select the node we want to set the color on
cytoscape.node.set_properties(nodeList='Selected',
                              propertyList='Fill Color',
                              valueList='Red',
                              verbose=True)

# And that's it !!
```